# Node.js and Apache on the same server

Tags: apache-2.2, node.js

What'd I'd like to do is have a node.js program be hosted in `public_html/<appname>` and be accessible by heading to `domainname.com:80/appname` - the server is Ubuntu 10.04, I'm using Apache as my HTTP server. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you probably need is mod_proxy and `ProxyPass` for Apache.

Run Apache on port 80, and use the `<Location>` config in Apache to pass the query along to Node.js which would be on another port e.g. 8080.

```
<Location /<appname>/>
    ProxyPass http://nodejsip:8080/
</Location>
```