# Do I have to open a port for mod_proxy and ProxyPass to work?

Tags: mod-proxy, port, proxypass

Here's my situation:

I have a server running Apache on `port 80`, a node.js application on `port 8000`, and I'd like to know if I have to open ports in order for `ProxyPass` and `mod_proxy` to work.

[Related](https://serverfault.com/questions/306062/node-js-and-apache-on-the-same-server/306064#306064)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port 80 has to be open as *Apache* will serve external requests on it.

If your *Node.js* application is running on the same host as *Apache* you don't need to open port 8000.

But if your *Node.js* application is running on different host than *Apache*, then you'll need to open port 8000 **only** for the IP of the server where *Apache* is running.

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like this:

```
ProxyPass http://localhost:8000
```

and default input policy is DROP:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

so, you still need to open port 8000 on the loopback interface:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```